# Eigenvalue for interacting Hamiltonian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

> Consider the Hamiltonian 
>   $$H=\omega_{1} a_{1}^\dagger a_{1}+\omega_{2}a_{2}^\dagger a_{2}+\alpha a_{3}^\dagger a_{3}(a_{1}^\dagger a_{2}+a_{2}^\dagger a_{1})$$
>   with 
>   $$ [a_\alpha^\dagger,a_\beta^\dagger]=[a_\alpha,a_\beta]=0,\qquad [a_\alpha,a_\beta^\dagger]=\delta_{\alpha\beta}.$$
>   Find the eigenvalue and eigenvector for this Hamiltonian.

I can deal with the first two term in this Hamiltonian, but how to deal with the interacting term.

Comment: Start by replacing $a^\dagger_3a_3$ by a constant $n$. Once you have solved this, use an eigenbasis $\lvert n_3\rangle$ of $a^\dagger_3a_3$ to incorporate the third mode.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $a_3^\dagger a_3$ commutes with $H$, so your states can be simultaneous eigenstates of both operators. Then you are left with a linear Hamiltonian that you can diagonalize.